# How can I create multiple partitions in a LUKS container using a gpt/mbr partition table in the container?

Tags: luks, cryptsetup, partition-table

Is it possible to have multiple partitions in a single LUKS or cryptsetup container? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

While I haven't found anything online describing such a setup, it turns out to work ok. Some advantages are you only have to enter your password once, and tools that can resize partitions work without having to know about the crypto layer. But there are other solutions for entering your password only once, and gnome partition editor is nowadays able to move/resize encrypted partitions too, so this is not really recommended. Plus, nobody seems to be doing this so there isn't much help online.

If you want to do this anyway:

- Create a LUKS encrypted volume any way you like and mount it.
  If the volume is named `cryptvolume` it will appear in `/dev/mapper/cryptvolume`.
- Open the volume with GParted: `gparted /dev/mapper/cryptvolume`
  Choose device > create partition table
  (alternatively, use a command line tool to create a partition table)
  Now you can create partitions in GParted any way you like.
- Create lines in `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab` if you want to mount the volume automatically on startup. There are may descriptions online of how to do that so I won't cover it here.

This should in principle be enough to have a working multi-partition LUKS container, and on Ubuntu 18.04 this works. Except that when rebooting this causes an error as systemd is not able to mount the encrypted partition(s). What's missing is that nothing tells the kernel to re-scan partition tables after the encrypted volume has been decrypted. The command to do that is `partprobe`. On systemd systems, to tell the system to run partprobe at the right time, put the following file at `/etc/systemd/system/partprobe.service`.

Replace the `cryptdisk1.mount` with the appropriate mount point(s) for your system and `/dev/mapper/cryptdisk` with the path to the decrypted LUKS device.

```
[Unit]
Description=partprobe after cryptsetup
# By default services depend on partitions being mounted. Leaving this out leads to cyclic dependencies.
DefaultDependencies=no
# We don't need to Requires=cryptsetup.target, as cryptsetup.target is always present
After=cryptsetup.target
# The mount target is named after the mount path.
# Run `systemctl list-dependencies local-fs.target` to list mount targets.
Before=cryptdisk1.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# You don't have to specify the path to the decrypted device, but doing so will speed up the boot a bit
ExecStart=/sbin/partprobe /dev/mapper/cryptdisk

[Install]
# Required by local-fs.target or by all the partitions in the LUKS container to be more specific 
RequiredBy=cryptdisk1.mount
```

After creating the file run `sudo systemctl enable partprobe.service` to enable the file.

This has been tested on Ubuntu 18.04 with GPT partitions. On different systems paths may differ. For non-systemd systems you will need to find a different way to run partprobe before the partitions are mounted.

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions`, `dmsetup table`, `losetup` to go with that?

Answer (score 0):

can't get it work with a 4.19 kernel and LUKS**2** format. userland can read/write the GPT on /dev/mapper/${name} but `partprobe` | `partx`| `blockdev` | `hdparm`all fails to expose the inner LUKS GPT to the kernel.

Comment: Well, you can map it out (with something that translates partition table to device mapper or losetup --partscan or similar) but yes, normally it's not expected to "just work" (hence my comment under the other answer). It's more common to do this with LVM instead of partition tables (and LVM takes care of the device mapper setup for you).

Comment: stumbled upon `kpartx` which curiously gets the exposure to kernel done where all the aforementioned tools failed...
___
If you wan to deploy several LVM software raid and not having to encrypt each LV then encrypting the main partition first is more useful

Comment: kpartx should be using the device mapper, so the kernel's own partition handling is not involved, is it? not sure what the issue is with LVM software RAID; that's per-LV, so you can still encrypt the entire PV, and not need a partition table on LUKS. (Same-disk RAID is not a good idea.)